# RabbitMQ bulk consuming messages solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm using RabbitMQ as a queue of different messages. When I consume this messages with **two different** consumers from **one queue**, I process them and insert processing results to a DB:

```
def consumer_callback(self, channel, delivery_tag, properties, message):
    result = make_some_processing(message)
    insert_to_db(result)
    channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag)
```

I want to bulk consume messages from queue, that will reduce DB load. Since RabbitMQ does not support bulk reading messages by consumers I'm going to do smth like this:

```
some_messages_list = []
def consumer_callback(self, channel, delivery_tag, properties, message):
    some_messages_list.append({delivery_tag: message})
    if len(some_messages_list) > 1000:
        results_list = make_some_processing_bulk(some_messages_list)
        insert_to_db_bulk(results_list)
        
        for tag in some_messages_list:
            channel.basic_ack(tag)
        some_messages_list.clear()
```

1. Messages are in queue before they all fully processed
2. If consumer falls or disconnects - messages stays safe

What do you think about that solution?
If it's okay, how can I get all unacknoleged messages anew, if consumer falls?

Comment: RabbitMQ might have a peek lock feature where a consumer can lock the message and acknowledge when complete, but unlock the message and it can be read by others if something goes wrong

Comment: Looks like it doesn't have this feature

Comment: This solution is good, but what if you don't have enough messages to full up the list to 1000. They will not get loaded until new messages come in. That sometimes could take time and until then you will be missing data. I was looking up at implementing timer for this problem.

Comment: @MarioKirov I use Timer based on python threading module. Timer makes consumer to process all messages every N seconds, but when its number is over than K, consumer start processing messages by batches.

Comment: Note, that u should use some kind of LockedList to protect messages from simultaneously reading by both timer and batch-consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this solution for several months and can say that it is pretty good. Till AMPQ doesn't provide feature for bulk consuming, we have to use some walkarounds like this.

*Note*: if you decided to use this solution, beware of concurent consuming with several consumers (threads), or use some **Locks** (I've used python threading.Lock module) to provide guarantees for no race conditions happens.